# Raycast from ScreenCenter hits object but does not return its tag

Tags: c#, unity, raycasting

Here is my code:

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class Crosshair : MonoBehaviour {
    public Camera cam;
    RaycastHit hit;
    Quaternion rot;
    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update ()
    {
        int x = Screen.width / 2;
        int y = Screen.height / 2;


        Ray ray = cam.ScreenPointToRay(new Vector3(x,y,0));
        Debug.DrawRay(ray.origin, ray.direction * 100, new Color(1f, 0.922f, 0.016f, 1f));
        rot = Quaternion.FromToRotation(Vector3.up, hit.normal);

        if (Physics.Raycast(transform.position, transform.forward, out hit))
        {
            Debug.Log("Now trying to locate enemy...");
           if(hit.transform && hit.transform.tag == "Enemy")
            {
                Debug.Log("Enemy Spotted!!");
            }
            else
            {
                Debug.Log("I tried bro...");
            }
        }


    }
}
```

as I can imagine `if(Physics.Raycast(transform.position, transform.forward, out hit))` is always false.

What am I not doing correctly?

Comment: Your code seems to be working, double check the colliders of enemy

Comment: We do not know, how did you debugged to know that the ray really hits the "enemy". If it was just visually, there is your problem. You always have to check the values rather then the visuals. Of course the ray is going through your object. But as long as there is no collider attached to the "enemy" object, the ray hit can't detect it because it doesn't know against what objects it should test colliding with.

Comment: @YoshSynergi Hmm, I checked in scene view where the ray is visible. The "target" object is 3d cube, with Box Collider, with Enemy as name & tag, and on Default Layer.

Comment: @HamzaHasan What should I be checking for?

Comment: Check the colliders and tag, if both are configured properly or not

Comment: @HamzaHasan as I replied to Yosh I checked in scene view where the ray is visible. The "target" object is 3d cube, with Box Collider, with Enemy as name & tag, and on Default Layer.

Comment: your code is actually correct, so what I can say is to check any invisible model or mesh having collider does exist in between ray and enemy?

Comment: Try as a debug check to iterate through all objects in the default layer and check the colliders. Maybe something is wrong in your declaration.

Comment: @HamzaHasan Supposedly it should work. the scene structure is HUD, Main Camera, Player. The Ray does not go through anything else except the enemy! :/

Comment: Disable hud and try again

Comment: @hamzahasan my canvas is in screen overlay mode you think that might be a problem?

Comment: Two quick questions: 1) what you are trying to do when hitting an object, is not to "return its tag", but rather you are not being able to detect the hit using tags. Is that the case? 2) what the canvas, which you just mentioned in the comments, have to do with that? I ask because to me it seems totally unrelated with the code you showed.

Comment: @MAnd 1) I want to get a debug message that the object has been hit! i tried with name and tag, still can't see if it works because it never enters that block of code.

2) A guy said to disable HUD, my hud is on a canvas, i thought maybe because it was in overlay mode it interrupted the ray somehow..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code works fine, what fixed the problem was clearing the cache! I've been working on this project for so many hours that it probably clogged out!

EDIT: To clear the cache I exited Unity, located my Unity's cache folder and deleted the contents. Loaded Unity up again and voila!

Comment: What does clearing the cache mean in terms of Unity?

Comment: @Byte56 I exited unity found my cache folder and deleted its contents, when I loaded it up again it was working. No idea how or why.

Comment: Probably just a rebuild of the project would have worked.

Comment: @Byte56 I tried that, it wouldn't work, I really have no idea what changed to be honest!

Comment: Huh, well, please update your answer to include that information.

Comment: @Byte56 I am sorry I didn't understand what I should include. Haven't I explained it already?

Comment: Include what you mean by clearing the cache and the other troubleshooting you did.